# Convert a URL stored as a variable into a href in JSON payload within Google Apps Script file

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps script which essentially sends key pieces of information from a Google Sheet to me via Slack, and one of these pieces is the URL of the sheet stored as the variable below:

```js
  var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();
```

I'm calling the 'sheetUrl' variable in the JSON payload and then running this function below:

```js
function sendToSlack_(url,payload) {
   var options =  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
}
```

I'd like to convert this 'sheetUrl' into a HREF rather than posting the entire Google Sheet URL which is ugly and lengthy, can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

This is a stripped-down version of the script file to give context:

```js
function sendToSlack() {

  var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/"; // channel in Slack  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();
  var stagingData = ss.getSheetByName('Staging');

  //Week No for current week & previous week
 var currentWeekNo = stagingData.getRange(2, 6).getValue();
 var previousWeekNo = stagingData.getRange(1, 6).getValue();
 
 // Quantities for current week vs Previous Week
 var sv15CurrentWeek = stagingData.getRange(6, 15).getValue();
 var sv15BasicCurrentWeek = stagingData.getRange(7, 15).getValue();
 var sv15BgCurrentWeek = stagingData.getRange(8, 15).getValue();
 var sv156CurrentWeek = stagingData.getRange(9, 15).getValue();

 var sv15PreviousWeek = stagingData.getRange(20, 15).getValue();
 var sv15BasicPreviousWeek = stagingData.getRange(21, 15).getValue();
 var sv15BgPreviousWeek = stagingData.getRange(22, 15).getValue();
 var sv156PreviousWeek = stagingData.getRange(23, 15).getValue();
 
 
 function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
  }
  
  var payload = {
     "channel" : "#reports",
     "type": "mrkdwn",
     "text" : 
      "*Week No. * - " + currentWeekNo + " vs " + previousWeekNo + "\n " 
       + "\n " 
       + sheetUrl
     }
  
  {
  sendToSlack_(url,payload)
}
function sendToSlack_(url,payload) {
   var options =  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Convert to HREF" ?  HREF is an attribute of an anchor tag.  Please explain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the Slack message, instead of seeing the entire Google Sheet URL, I would ideally like this to be a hyperlink with say "Click here" to view the sheet

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you create the slack message.  Also it make to sense to stringify a string.  You normally stringify objects with property names.

Comment: I added most of the script to my original message above, but essentially it contains the variables:   var payload = {
     "channel" : "#reports",
     "type": "mrkdwn",
     "text" : 
      "*Week No. * - " + currentWeekNo + " vs " + previousWeekNo + "\n " 
       + "\n " 
       + sheetUrl
     }

Comment: I stringify the payload, which is where this sheeturl variable sits. I have tried to use the anchor tags in this payload but I just can't seem to figure it out. @cooper, can you see my example above?

Comment: I see your example but I still don't know what you question is.  What is your google apps script question?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this type of thing

Comment: {
 "blocks": [
  {
   "type": "section",
   "text": {
    "type": "mrkdwn",
    "text": "This message contains a URL http://someurl/\n
   }
  }
 ]
}

Comment: I can achieve it like this: "<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/|This is a link>" but I want to use the variable var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();

Comment: Like this: "<sheeturl|This is a link>"

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out: "<" + sheetUrl + "|Link>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now wrapping the anchors and including the variable between the plus signs as shown below

"<" + sheetUrl + "|Link>"